# Build to device with automatic provisioning xcode 4, iPad 4.3.5 - fails with 'no issues'

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, build, provisioning

I can't for the life of me get my App to build to my iPad in xcode 4.0.1 using the 'Team Provisioniong Profile' from the xcode organizer 'automatic device provisioning'.

The app buils perfectly to the simulator but when I build to the iPad 4.3.5 it says 'Build Failed - No issues'. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Please let me know what code/info you would need... I can't post an error message cause there is none... Hours of googling and nothing is working..

Thomas

edit: I'm downloading xcode 4.1 right now, does anyone know if that fixes it?

Comment: Could it be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363564/xcode-4-build-failed-no-issues

(using underscore in project / target name..)

Comment: No I am using all one word for targets/project name and the bundle identifier is XXXXXXXXXX.* (with my code from provisioning portal)

Comment: One of the posts suggest to create a new project and setup provisioning for that. If that works fine, you could add code from the other project and keep narrowing down.
There where some other suggestions also, apart from underscore.

Comment: I've tried just about everyone of them already. Nothing. I'm trying xcode 4.1 right now.

Answer (score 1):

Updated xcode to 4.1 and it deploys to iPad now.