# Building failed in device but no error is showing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I totally stuck here.

I finished my app and when trying to build with the distribution certificates it is saying build failed,but no error is showing.

When i googled some one told to remove the ".*" from bundle identifier and then it is running.

But when uploading with our ".*" application loader is rejecting the binary..

How can i overcome from this issue.

Please kindly help me.Im totally stuck here.

Hoping for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you changed code signing identity in Build Settings?

Comment: yes.i have given the bundle identifier as com.companyname.*.

Comment: set your bundel identifier as com.yourcompname.yourapp name not use *. and its to be same as you create in your developer a/c

Comment: check with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363564/xcode-4-build-failed-no-issues

Comment: @AnshulJain,thankyou.please give it as answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your bundle identifier as com.yourcompname.yourapp name not use *. and its to be same as you create in your developer a/c....