# build failed without error in xcode 4.4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.4

My project is running fine up to xcode version 4.3, when I updated it to version 4.4 it shows failed without any error on building the code, I have tried searching over Google and try every possible step but not able to solve my problem.

Comment: Provide some more details on what the error is that you are seeing.

Comment: it doesn't showing any error, on building it just failed

Comment: close xcode, quit xcode . then reopen it. sometimes it happns. maybe it will help you.

Comment: @Chinttu I have already tried that, no success.

Comment: Also try doing a clean, and deleting the Derived Data.  Hard to diagnose without any info about the project. Also, give this a read if you haven't already to see if any of these solutions help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363564/xcode-4-build-failed-no-issues

Comment: Are you still on lion or mountain lion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved my problem by installing command line tools from

> XCode > Preferences > Downloads > Components > command line tools.

Comment: You should accept this answer to help others with the same problem.

Comment: @Mayank can you please tell how you find your issue using command line tool? it would be very helpful.

Comment: I haven't found any issue, just installing command line tools solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue.  I didn't realise I had somehow filtered the errors by a single space at the bottom of the errors tab :(.  Removing the filter at the bottom of the errors page sorted it all out.