# Xcode: Build Failed, but no error messages

Tags: xcode, build

Using Xcode 4.5.1. Our project has been building fine for the last three months, but suddenly, when I try to build, it says "Build failed", but does not show any errors on the triangle exclamation mark tab, nor does it give a reason when it pops up build failed.

We have not changed the bundle identifier, or any other project properties. I tried a clean, then build, but no luck.

What may be causing the problem?

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363564/xcode-4-build-failed-no-issues), but none of the solutions apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 4: Build Failed, No Issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363564/xcode-4-build-failed-no-issues)

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Figured it out. On the tab with three lines in a speech bubble, it shows a build log. I guess my storyboard file had become corrupt during the last git pull.

[image]

**For Xcode 12+**
[image: screenshot of Xcode 12 toolbar]

Comment: I had just general issue in code with such symptoms. I guessed clang can pass error messages in code into issues tab...

Comment: really a great answer. I have build 4-5 times. even restarted the xcode

Comment: Just chiming in with a hint that might help others. I navigated to the build log via the icon shown for Xcode 12+ above. I saw that there was a search term in the filter which didn't match any of the messages, so nothing was displayed. I cleared the filter and then I got all the build log messages as I hoped.

Comment: thanks~ I faced same issue but solved now

Answer (score 213):

You can see reasons for failure on `Report Navigator` present in *Navigator window.*

- Open Navigator by pressing `Hide/Show Navigator` button present in top-left side of Xcode.

[image: Screenshot 1]

- Open `Report Navigator` by pressing last button present on list of buttons in Navigator window.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Here you can view reasons either `By Group` or `By Time`

Comment: **This is like** ***I have my spec on my head and I am searching all over the world...***

Answer (score 109):

Click the last icon in the top bar of the left most panel in your Xcode window to reveal the secret *Archive* build errors.

[image]

It will likely be something related to code signing if you are able to build and run the app, but not Archive.  Further googling of your error message should resolve that now that it has been revealed.

Answer (score 53):

Click the last icon in the top bar of the left most panel in your Xcode window to reveal the "secret" Archive build errors. I had permission issues which solved for me.

[image: Xcode - Report Navigator]

Answer (score 6):

If you changed the Build System to the new one, change back to the Standard. It solved for me.

[image: Build System]

Comment: Wow, that's cool. On my Xcode it was standard build system. I changed into new build system and the problem was solved .

Comment: File > Workspace settings

Comment: Actually, here select Show all issues, instead of "Show issues for active scheme only" and you're good. The new build system has a huge performance advantage over the old one with Swift projects.

Answer (score 2):

Faced same issue with xCode 8 the reason was that my Apple Id session expired and xCode was not able to renew it because of network connection problems once i signed in with my Apple id in preferences. I was able to build normally again

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me while I was writing in `Swift 4.1` in `XCode 9.3`. I use `RxSwift` also. It never happened while I was writing in `Objective C`. There were no any logs in `Report Navigator` too. Project just compiled without errors, then failed. Couldn't figure out why.

In my case what I did and it helped:

1. Commit changes in Git and then discard changes in XCode if it shows "M" near files
2. Clear derived data: Xcode -> Preferences -> location
3. Clean build folder: Shift + Cmd + Alt + K
4. Restart XCode

After this project tried to compile and showed errors. The error was here:

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: timingsDict, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let pTiming = try decoder.decode(PTiming.self, from: jsonData)
    observer.onNext(timing)
    observer.onCompleted()
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    observer.onError(error)
}
```

I passed wrong variable name in `observer.onNext(timing)`. It should have been `pTiming`.

Answer (score 2):

There might be no free disk space left.

Comment: hi and welcome to SO! note that there is already an accepted answer for this question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14625517/6619250.

Comment: Mate, you saved me! This was the case with me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jason. You must did something wrong. It is Xcode's bug that it could not produce the error. Just move back on your path. Open screens you edited/opened last time. In My case `;` was missing in one controller.

Answer (score 1):

This will also often happen if the "magical" macOS automatically restarts XCode after boot. That auto-started XCode instance will be completely broken. Quit and restart.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the fixing from here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/715103?page=3

I think I found the cause of the problem, on my system anyway...

After a bunch of digging around, I found that the case of the folder associated with the XCode group containing my source code didn't match the case on the file system. (ie. the XCode group "Weather" was associated with "/Users/....../Weather" but the folder on the file system was called "/Users/....../weather".)

When I used the little folder icon in the inspector to re-associate it with the folder, the case was corrected and whammo all my missing error messages suddenly reappeared.

I'm guessing that at sometime along the line of XCode 14 betas, it started caring about case sensitivity, so my project file that used to work fine was now incorrect as far as the linter was concerned.

So: Check that the case of the folders associated with your XCode groups match the file system, and use the little folder icon to correct it if they're not.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Xcode -> Preferences(command + ,) -> General Tab -> Uncheck **Show Live Issues** This helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Other answers helped me find the *Report Navigator.* The only error displayed was:

> Build operation failed without specifying any errors. Individual build
>   tasks may have failed for unknown reasons.  One possible cause is if
>   there are too many (possibly zombie) processes; in this case,
>   rebooting may fix the problem.

I fixed this by closing the Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

With me it was the dev provisioning profile I was using for that scheme. I changed it to release and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try next scenario:

- Restart Xcode
- check that `.swift` file with test functions contains

```
import XCTest
class <name>Tests: XCTestCase {
    //...
}
```

*If you have `Cannot find viewcontroller in scope` error -> remove classes from Test Target membership

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I had multiple targets in my app, each targeting different versions of iOS.

I had added a bunch of structs that implemented protocols/classes only available on later versions of iOS (widget stuff: `AppIntentTimelineProvider`, etc). I fixed the issue by adding `@available` to all those structs:

```swift
@available(iOS 17.0, *)
struct DeckQuery: EntityQuery {
```