# Xcode Project Build Failed With No Errors

Tags: ios, xcode

XCode has recently stopped showing all build errors and I'm at a loss for how to correct it. Whether it be something like forgetting to put in an initial view controller, misspelling/not declaring a variable name, or pretty much anything else that would cause the project not to build will no longer show up. I've built the project on other Macbooks and it showed me the errors so I was able to correct it, but I can't get it to show on mine.

Comment: When posting you should provide enough information for others to help. What is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message. That's the issue. I'm just getting 'Build Failed', without any errors or warnings

Comment: If it works on other Macs, I'd try reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: for your ref, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625389/xcode-build-failed-but-no-error-messages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue might occur because of Xcode.

(1) Quit and relaunch **Xcode**.

(2) Clean (**⌘+shift+K**) and build (**⌘+shift+B**) your project.

If that not case, check out he answer here by [Kris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40665890/7995508) i.e.

> Click the last icon in the top bar of the left most panel in your
>   Xcode window to reveal the secret Archive build errors.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea as to how to fix this permanently? I've tried all of the above and nothing seems to work

Comment: Try clearing the derived data (Organizer->Projects / ⌘+shift + 2) and then clean (⌘+shift+K).