# Archiving stops without any context, but It works well while building on devices

Tags: ios, xcode

I've tried to archive my project, but every time it stops at the same place. There is no error has been thrown in this case.

[image]

Anyone has faced this issue or any way to find what causes it to stop.

[image]

Comment: Look at the build report to get a clue on where the hangup is. But then you will just have to experiment.

Comment: Thanks, @matt I've checked there. But still not getting the actual clue I'm looking for. I'm updating question here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 4: Build Failed, No Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363564/xcode-4-build-failed-no-issues)

Comment: @KiranJasvanee please delete the derived data and try again and let me know you updated your code form swift2.3/3 to swift 4.x/5.x

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been resolved.
Normally the way code has been done should have been working fine, but it didn't.

We had just declared one array, which was removing it's all values before inserting new once.

```
var arrayDictDeviceNames = [DeviceEndPointName]()
arrayDictDeviceNames.removeAll()
arrayDictDeviceNames.append(DeviceEndPointName.init())
```

Yes, `arrayDictDeviceNames.append(DeviceEndPointName.init())` this statement was stopping that achieve. Weird.
**Well, what we have done is to alloc our array - `arrayDictDeviceNames` again and it worked fine.**